# User registration with payment option

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I need a help in new user registration with payment option with 2/3 types of user, Please tell which is the good module/method.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to install ubercart module for Drupal.
Then take a look at [this](http://www.ubercart.org/docs/user/3366/selling_site_access_role_promotions)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use http://drupal.org/project/ubercart module. It is an e-commerce solution for Drupal. Its easy to learn how to use it. Google for tutorials.

Using Ubercart Roles module you can "Assign permanent or expirable roles based on product purchases"

Its also a good idea to use a Ubercart Installation Profile see: http://drupal.org/project/uberdrupal

Answer (score 0):

I had the most success with lm_paypal.  Ubercart did the job, but the management overhead was too much - I just needed a way to sign up subscribers, give them their subscription period, remind them when their subscription is almost up, and use Paypal as the payment gateway.  There was no need to install a full-fledged commerce system *if* this is all you're going to do.  If you need a full-fledged commerce system, then Ubercart is definitely the go-to suite.